# Cannot increase number of replicas. Leading to Unassigned shards even though i have enough nodes

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-2.0

In my ES cluster i have 19 nodes. Following is my cluster health.

> {
>     "cluster_name" : "AVS",
>     "status" : "green",
>     "timed_out" : false,
>     "number_of_nodes" : 19,
>     "number_of_data_nodes" : 19,
>     "active_primary_shards" : 23,
>     "active_shards" : 125,
>     "relocating_shards" : 0,
>     "initializing_shards" : 0,
>     "unassigned_shards" : 0,
>     "delayed_unassigned_shards" : 0,
>     "number_of_pending_tasks" : 0,
>     "number_of_in_flight_fetch" : 0
>   }

Currently all my indices are GREEN. Now for one of my indices, it's current settings are 10 shards and 5 replicas. But if I increases number of replicas from 5 to any number more than that, all of new replicated shards are being in state UNASSIGNED.

Considering number of nodes i have i am assuming i can have more than 5 replicas. What am i missing?

Comment: could it be you have [forced_awareness](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/allocation-awareness.html#forced-awareness) setting on ?

Comment: i looked for settings there is no additional setting.

Comment: just to confirm you checked the [transient settings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/cluster-update-settings.html#_precedence_of_settings)  as well as config ?

Comment: Do you have enough disk space to create those shards?

Comment: @keety i ran curl -XGET localhost:9200/_cluster/settings and the returned value is this. {"persistent":{},"transient":{}}

Comment: @AndreiStefan, most of the disk space is free. less than 10% is used.

Comment: That doesn't account for the settings in the config file did you check the config too ?

Comment: Do you mean config for the specific index?

Comment: no i meant the node config file usually `elasticsearch.yml` or you can check the [node settings](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/cluster-nodes-info.html) Example : `curl -XGET <host>/_nodes/settings`